# Why is there a error when I try to rename a column after the over clause?

Tags: sql, over-clause

I want to rename a column after calculating the difference between current row and previous row by using over clause (windows function)

However, I cannot run it and it shows that I have a error in my sql syntax

```
select country,year,
avg(oil_consumption) OVER (partition by country 
  order BY year 
     ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND current row )
     as 3_year_moving_average, (3_year_moving_average-lag(3_year_moving_average,1) over (partition by country) **as** difference_between_previous_current
from owid_energy_data
```

> Error at the second as (bolded)

Comment: parentheses are unbalanced

Comment: And you cannot compute an expression as a column value and then reference that result using the column name in the same `SELECT` clause - all column values are computed *as if* they're being computed in parallel, they cannot be interdependent.

Comment: May I know how can I reuse that calculation then? I have tried using user-defined varaible but it is session specific @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Thank you! I have solved this issue :) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @Shannon - depending on which RDBMS you're using (if you want specifics, please add an appropriate tag as the [tag:sql] tag suggests you do), there'll be options to apply lateral joins, CTEs or subqueries such that you place the earlier calculation into a *separate* `SELECT` clause that a later `SELECT` clause can then reference